# How many words of length n over the alphabet {a,b,c} such that the sub-word aa does not appear?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The question asks that it be solved as a recurrence relation, as in set up a recurrence relation then determine initial values to give a solution. However I am not really confident setting up recurrence relations. I know that there are $3^n$ different words over this alphabet but not how to determine how many do not contain the sub-word.

Comment: Hint: Suppose that the first letter is $a$, what could the second letter be?  Suppose that the first letter is not $a$, what could the second letter be?

Comment: So you can always add $b$ and $c$ to the end of the word but you can only add $a$ if the previous did not end with $a$? This helps understanding the problem but I still don't know how to model it into a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $a_n$ be the number of strings which satisfy the conditions of length $n$.

- If a string begins with $b$ or $c$, then you are left with a string of length $n-1$, which can start with any character.  How many strings are there of this type (it is related to $a_{n-1}$)?
- If a string begins with $a$, then the second letter *must* be a $b$ or $c$, then you are left with a string of length $n-2$, which can start with any character.  How many strings are there of this type (it is related to $a_{n-2}$)?